# Deploy Heroku projeto Maven com vários módulos

Tags: java, maven, heroku

Tenho um projeto Maven (web) composto por um projeto empacotador (`packaging = pom`) e diversos módulos. Quero fazer o deploy desse projeto no Heroku.

Dúvidas:

1. **Onde** deve ficar o `Procfile`? No projeto empacotador ou no projeto web?
2. **Como** deve ficar o `Procfile`?

---

`pom.xml` do projeto empacotador:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>valor.alterado.para.stackoverflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>stackoverflow-package</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <modules>
    <module>../stackoverflow-web</module>
    <module>../stackoverflow-service</module>
    <module>../stackoverflow-business</module>
    <module>../stackoverflow-model</module>
    <module>../stackoverflow-commons</module>
  </modules>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seu `Procfile` deve ficar na raiz do projeto, ou seja, no mesmo diretório que seu projeto empacotador está.

Se sua aplicação for um servidor web e o artefato final for um arquivo `jar`, então seu `Procfile` deve ficar assim: `web: java -jar caminho-para-a-sua-aplicacao/seu-artefato.jar`.

Para simplificar você pode definir no `pom` do seu submódulo o nome do artefato final:

```
<build>
    <finalName>seu-artefato</finalName>
    ...
</build>
```

**Explicação**: Um Procfile contém um número de declarações de tipo de processo, cada um em uma nova linha. Cada tipo de processo é uma declaração de um comando que é executado quando um dyno desse tipo de processo é iniciado. Por exemplo, se um tipo de processo **web** for declarado, então quando um dyno desse tipo é iniciado, o comando associado ao tipo de processo da web será executado. Isso pode significar começar um servidor web, por exemplo. Resumindo, em seu `Procfile` você deve definir o tipo e como sua aplicação deverá ser executada.

Mais informações podem ser vistas na [página](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) do Heroku: